# Python TypeError when building query string

Tags: python, typeerror

I am building a query string.

```
query = "SELECT seqid, date, name, steamid, team, text, type, '%s' as triggerword, '%s' as weight FROM chatlogs WHERE date > '%s' AND text LIKE '%%%s%%' ORDER BY DATE" % (word, weight, self.setting['LAST_RUN_TIME'], word)
```

If I print the string, it returns correctly:

```
SELECT seqid, date, name, steamid, team, text, type, 'hunting_term' as triggerword, '0.01' as weight FROM chatlogs WHERE date > '2012-04-18 23:47:58.439124' AND text LIKE '%hunting_term%' ORDER BY DATE
```

However, it then fails with a TypeError exception:
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Full code:

```
import database

mysqldb = database.Connection('localhost','mydb',user='myuser',password='mypass')

word = 'hunting_term'
weight = 0.01
setting = dict({'LAST_RUN_TIME':'2012-04-18 23:47:58.439124'})

query = "SELECT seqid, date, name, steamid, team, text, type, '%s' as triggerword, '%s' as weight FROM chatlogs WHERE date > '%s' AND text LIKE '%%%s%%' ORDER BY DATE" % (word, weight, setting['LAST_RUN_TIME'], word)
print query

for message in mysqldb.query(query):        # This is the line it throws the exception on
    print "A row"
```

database is from the [tornado](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/database.py) package

Comment: What happens if you change `'%%%s%%'` to `'%%%%%s%%%%'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that the eventual call to MySQLdb looks something like this:

```
query = "SELECT seqid, date, name, steamid, team, text, type, 'hunting_term' as triggerword, '0.01' as weight FROM chatlogs WHERE date > '2012-04-18 23:47:58.439124' AND text LIKE '%hunting_term%' ORDER BY DATE"
db.cursor().execute(query, ())
```

The first argument to `db.cursor().execute()` should be a format string, and the second argument should be the replacements for that format string, you can see this in the [MySQLdb docs](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples).  In other words it will execute the following code:

```
query % ()
```

As you can see, this will cause the same TypeError:

```
>>> query % ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

This means that any literal `%` that you want MySQL to see needs to be a `%%` when it is seen by `db.cursor().execute()`, so you should be able to fix this by changing your original format string to the following:

```
query = "SELECT seqid, date, name, steamid, team, text, type, '%s' as triggerword, '%s' as weight FROM chatlogs WHERE date > '%s' AND text LIKE '%%%%%s%%%%' ORDER BY DATE" % (word, weight, self.setting['LAST_RUN_TIME'], word)
```

However the correct way to do this is to let MySQLdb perform the substitutions for you, which would change your code to the following:

```
query = "SELECT seqid, date, name, steamid, team, text, type, %s as triggerword, %s as weight FROM chatlogs WHERE date > %s AND text LIKE %s ORDER BY DATE"
parameters = (word, weight, setting['LAST_RUN_TIME'], '%%%s%%' % word)
for message in mysqldb.query(query, *parameters):
    print "A row"
```

Comment: Letting MySQLdb perform the substitutions for you is preferred because it will protect against sql injection.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, if that's the way MySQLdb performs substitutions then it is an invitation to SQL injection, not a protection from it.

Comment: @MarkRansom, actually letting MySQLdb do it for you is safer, because it performs all of the necessary escaping to make sure that a `%s` always becomes a single value.  I simplified what happens on the MySQLdb side, it is more complicated than `query % parameters`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I wrote that after perusing the source: `query = query % db.literal(args)`.  I assume `db.literal` does the proper escaping.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski and F.J, OK I believe you.